# How to get Excel VBA code to save a filtered CSV as a new CSV?

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv

I cannot get the Excel macro addin to take a filtered CSV imported into Excel 
and save it as a new CSV file. When it saves with a new name the file is blank. It does not contain the filtered data.

I've searched this site and others and I am using code based upon various code samples found here and elsewhere. I've included a `MsgBox` to review the path and filename before it is saved and it all looks fine. When I check and return the count of the number of workbooks, it simply shows a count of 1. So I don't believe it is seeing the Addin as a workbook.

```
If Right(Workbooks(1).path, 1) <> "\" Then
    path = Workbooks(1).path & "\Filtered_" & Workbooks(1).Name
Else
    path = Workbooks(1).path & "Filtered_" & Workbooks(1).Name
End If

MsgBox path

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path, FileFormat:=xlCSV

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox "Filtering Complete", vbOKOnly, "Filtered CSV"
```

I'm expecting to open the file and see the filtered results. Instead, it is simply blank when I open the new file.

Comment: If `ThisWorkbook` is an add-in, as you reference, it doesn't sound like you should be saving a copy of it... Where/how are you filtering the data? I feel like some code is missing.

Comment: The same addin (Excel-VBA macro) is using ".AutoFilter" to filtering columns is the CSV source tab, selects that data (.SpecialCells) to copy and save to a new tab. After copying to the new tab, the "Addin" deletes the source tab and saves the filtered data as a new CSV file. Regardless, it saves the CSV but there is no data in the file?  -- Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change "ThisWorkbook" to "Workbooks(1)":

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path, FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

ThisWorkbook refers to the "Addin" being used and not the actual workbook being edited.